# Possible values of refX, refY in an SVG marker

Tags: html, svg, w3c

In the [W3C documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-markers/#MarkerElementRefYAttribute), we can read that the `refY` attribute of a svg `<marker>` can take the values `top`, `center`, `bottom` but when I try it, I have the following error:

`Error: <marker> attribute refY: Expected length, "center".`

Here is a snippet, when you run it, you can see the error in your browser console (*I'm using Chrome 70.0.3538.77 on Debian*). I know I can put the value `6` (in this case) to center it, I just want to know if I misunderstand the documentation or if it's an error.

```css
svg{
background-color:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="12" markerHeight="12" refX="0" refY="center" markerUnits="strokeWidth">
      <path d="M0,0 L0,12 L12,6 z" fill="red" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="50" y2="50" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" marker-end="url(#arrow)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking at would seem to be an abandoned draft of a marker specification.

The proposed next version of the SVG specification is [SVG 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/painting.html#MarkerElementRefXAttribute). This is being implemented by browser manufacturers although such implementation of new features is spotty as you've discovered. You can see in that specification text that says

> We will add top/center/bottom, left/center/right keywords to refX/refY on marker/symbol. Resolved at London F2F. Values inspired by 'background-position'.

The [SVG 1.1 text](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#MarkerElementRefXAttribute) does not support top, center or bottom. If you stick to what's in SVG 1.1 you have a much better chance of things working.

At some point SVG 2 will either contain new features because the majority of browsers support it, or the new features will get dropped from the specification. At the moment SVG 2 is still a work in progress, both as a specification and as a target for browsers.